# Is "were I you" archaic?

Tags: subjunctive-mood, conditionals, archaicisms

Would the following usage be considered archaic?

> **Were I you**, I would ask her for a date.

Comment: I wouldn't think so.

Comment: Nor I, though I am a bit archaic myself and should come with a government health warning for Millennials. On the other hand, I can't envision a Brit actually saying this. Even if a subjunctive-loving wrinkly, he would be more likely to say "If I were you". Youngers would probably say "In your shoes" or its variants.

Comment: Grammatical constructions don't become archaic overnight. The subjunctive is clearly on its way out, but some people still use it. So the answer to your question is not a simple *yes* or *no*.

Comment: Not archaic but certainly formal.

Comment: What do you mean by archaic? Rarely used nowadays, although it was much more common in the past? Or so out-of-use that people will look at you funny if you use it? It fits the first, but not the second.

Comment: I find it poetic, and I will try to use it henceforth.

Comment: I meant in the sense that it is so out-of-use people will look at you funny if you use it.

Answer (score 5):

This is not archaic, but it is used infrequently.  This combines both inversion and the subjunctive, and use of the latter has become more endangered for the younger speakers of English.  Despite this, most speakers would use "if I were you" to describe the same sentiment.  Inversion is apparently more endangered than the subjunctive.

Were I you, I'd stick with "if I were you".

Answer (score 1):

The normal form is: If I were you". Such a formula for irreality can also have the form "Were I you" but I would say that is a formula you can find in written form, in novels.